# flip uv map without numpad

Tags: uv, shortcut

I try to flip a uv map in uv editor mode. I read that S, X, -1 should do the trick but I don't have a numpad and it doesn't work even with the emulate numpad option switched on.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the *UV island/islands* you want to flip, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*. Change the *Pivot* type to **Bounding Box Center**. Then go to ***UVs***-->***Mirror***-->***X axis***.

[image]

Comment: Also you could press `Ctrl`+`M` for mirroring to make operation a bit faster.